# Bug in UpdateSubscription.tpl?

Tags: civicontribute

In the CiviContribute module is a form that allows a recurring contribution to be updated.  This form uses the /civicrm/templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/UpdateSubscription.tpl template, which has the code  `({ts}every{/ts} {$frequency_interval} {$frequency_unit})` in it.  However, this comes out as "(every )".  It appears that the variables are not being set.

I am accessing this page via a link sent when the recurring payment was set up.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Thanks